# How can I select top rows of a dataframe,which sum of one column is 90% of sum of that original one?

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's see one example,if we have got a dataframe like below :

```
  category  value  
0        A     4  
1        B     3  
2        C     2  
3        D     1
```

since sum values of top 3 rows is 9 ,is there a quick way to select that part of dataframe,so I can get :

```
  category  value  
0        A     4  
1        B     3  
2        C     2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create another column with a cumulative % and filter on that.

```
df['cumpct'] = df['value'].cumsum()/ df['value'].sum()*100
df[df['cumpct] <= 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the cumulative sum of values as follows:

Code:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_data = """
index      category  value  
0        A     4  
1        B     3  
2        C     2  
3        D     1  """
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_data), sep="\s+", engine="python")
    df.sort_values(by=["value"], ascending=[False], inplace=True)
    df["cumsum"] = df["value"].cumsum() / df["value"].sum()
    sel_df = df[df["cumsum"] <= 0.9]
    print(sel_df)
```

Result:

```
   index category  value  cumsum
0      0        A      4     0.4
1      1        B      3     0.7
2      2        C      2     0.9
```